# groovy "MissingMethodException" RESTAPI call

Tags: exception, groovy, method-missing

I am trying to access data from `RESTAPI` using groovy code where i am getting error as below:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.call() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: wait(), chars(), any(), wait(long), take(int), tap(groovy.lang.Closure)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:70)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:182)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeClosure(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:586)
```

The error is coming mostly on the below part of the lines from code :

```
    String requestString = getRequestStringPrefix() + sb.toString()
    readHistory(authToken,ricMap,outFile)
    writeInstFile(outFile)
```

I am really new in the groovy coding and not understanding exactly the cause of the issue and how to resolve this issue in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this `getRequestStringPrefix()` you are calling a method with that name or as a shortcut a method `call()` on the underlying object, then it looks like `getRequestStringPrefix.call()`.

I'm not sure what your intention was, but the line:

```
String requestString = getRequestStringPrefix() + sb.toString()
```

should look like

```
String requestString = getRequestStringPrefix + sb.toString()
```

because the variable `getRequestStringPrefix` (a strange name for a var) is defined as String further down:

```
String getRequestStringPrefix = """{
  "ExtractionRequest": {..."""
```